# Error en tiempo de ejecución: Variable de tipo Object o la variable de bloque With no está establecida vb6

Tags: vb6

Lo que se pretende hacer es un programa que convierta números en diferentes bases

Definí la siguiente clase llamada `Class1` con estas variables

```
  Public numero As String
  Public DeBase As String
  Public toBase As Integer
  Public Convertir As Object
```

En el formulario principal tengo este código:

```
    Option Explicit
    Dim clsConvert As New Class1 
    
    Private Sub Command1_Click() 
    
    With clsConvert 
    
    ' Inputobx para el número a convertir 
    .numero = InputBox(" Ingrese el numero a convertir ") 
    
    If .numero = "" Then Exit Sub 
    ' base del número (Decimal - binario o Hexadecimal) 
    .DeBase = InputBox("Ingrese la base del número que ingresó :" & _ 
    " Binario = 2, Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16")

    If Not (Len(.DeBase)) And Not (IsNumeric(.DeBase)) Then Exit Sub ' Si el usuario pulsa Cancelar el _
    InputBox se cierra sin tirar error de no coincidencia de tipos

    If .DeBase = 0 Then Exit Sub 
    
    ' diálogo para especificar la base de la conversión _ 
    ( binario - decimal o hexadecimal -) 
    
    .tobase = InputBox("Ingrese el número de la " & _ 
    "base a convertir : Binario = 2, " & _ 
    "Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16") 
    
    If .toBase = 0 Then Exit Sub 
    
    ' este método Convierte el número y muestra el resultado 
    MsgBox .Convertir(.Numero, .DeBase, .toBase), vbInformation 
    
    End With 
    
End Sub 

' función que convierte de número Hexadecimal a Decimal 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function HexToDec(ByVal HexStr As String) As Double 
    Dim mult As Double 
    Dim DecNum As Double 
    Dim ch As String 
    mult = 1 
    DecNum = 0 
    
    Dim i As Integer 
    For i = Len(HexStr) To 1 Step -1 'Len es longitud de la Cadena
        ch = Mid(HexStr, i, 1) 'Mid es la subcadena i es la posición final y el 1 es la cantidad de caracteres que se pretende extraer
        If (ch >= "0") And (ch <= "9") Then 
            DecNum = DecNum + (Val(ch) * mult) 'Val convierte a número la Cadena o el carácter
        Else 
            If (ch >= "A") And (ch <= "F") Then 
                DecNum = DecNum + ((Asc(ch) - Asc("A") + 10) * mult) 
            Else 
                If (ch >= "a") And (ch <= "f") Then 
                    DecNum = DecNum + ((Asc(ch) - Asc("a") + 10) * mult) ' La función Asc _ nos permite obtener el código ASCII de un de terminado carácter.
                Else 
                    HexToDec = 0 
                    Exit Function 
                End If 
            End If 
        End If 
        mult = mult * 16 
    Next i 
    HexToDec = DecNum 
End Function 


' función que convierte de número Decimal a Hexadecimal 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function DecToHex(ByVal DecNum As Double) As String 
    Dim remainder As Integer 
    Dim HexStr As String 
    HexStr = "" 
    Do While DecNum <> 0 
        remainder = DecNum Mod 16 
        If remainder <= 9 Then 
            HexStr = Chr(Asc(remainder)) & HexStr 'La Función Chr actúa a la _ inversa de la función Asc, esto quiere decir, que a partir de un determinado número nos devolverá el caracter ASCII.
        Else 
            HexStr = Chr(Asc("A") + remainder - 10) & HexStr 
        End If 
        DecNum = DecNum \ 16 
    Loop 
    If HexStr = "" Then HexStr = "0"
    DecToHex = HexStr 
End Function 


' función que convierte de número Decimal a Binario 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function DecToBin(ByVal DecNum As Double) As String 
    Dim BinStr As String 
    BinStr = "" 
    Do While DecNum <> 0 
        If (DecNum Mod 2) = 1 Then 
            BinStr = "1" & BinStr 
        Else 
            BinStr = "0" & BinStr 
        End If 
        DecNum = DecNum \ 2 
    Loop 
    If BinStr = "" Then BinStr = "0000" 
    DecToBin = BinStr 
End Function 


' función que convierte de número Binario a número Decimal 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function BinToDec(ByVal BinStr As String) As Double 
    Dim mult As Double 
    Dim DecNum As Double 
    mult = 1 
    DecNum = 0 
    
    Dim i As Integer 
    For i = Len(BinStr) To 1 Step -1 
        If Mid(BinStr, i, 1) = "1" Then 
            DecNum = DecNum + mult 
        End If 
        mult = mult * 2 
    Next i 
    BinToDec = DecNum 
End Function 


' función que convierte de número Hexadecimal a número Bbinario 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
Public Function HexToBin(ByVal HexStr As String) As String 
    Dim BinStr As String 
    BinStr = "" 
    Dim i As Integer 
    For i = 1 To Len(HexStr) 
        BinStr = BinStr & DecToBin(HexToDec(Mid(HexStr, i, 1))) 
    Next i 
    HexToBin = BinStr 
End Function 


' función que convierte de número Binario a Hexadecimal 
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function BinToHex(ByVal BinStr As String) As String 
    Dim HexStr As String
    HexStr = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(BinStr) Mod 4 Step 4
        HexStr = HexStr & DecToHex(BinToDec(Mid(BinStr, i + 1, Len(BinStr))))
    Next i
    BinToHex = HexStr
End Function 

'función que retorna el valor 
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 

Public Function Convertir(ByVal numToConvert As Object, _ 
                 ByVal DeBase As Integer, _ 
                 ByVal tobase As Integer) As Object 
    
    
        Select Case DeBase 
            
        Case 2 
            If Not Verificar(Numero, "01") Then 
                MsgBox "Base 2 sólo puede contener 0 y 1" 
                Exit Function 
            End If 
        Case 10 
            If Not Verificar(Numero, "0123456789") Then 
                MsgBox "Base 10 sólo puede contener de '0' a '9'." 
                Exit Function 
            End If 
        Case 16 
            If Not Verificar(Numero, "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef") Then 
                MsgBox "La Base 16 sólo puede contener " & _ 
                    " de '0' a '9' y de 'A' a 'F' o de 'a' a 'f'." 
                Exit Function 
            End If 
        End Select 
    
    If DeBase = tobase Then 
        Convertir = numToConvert 
        Exit Function 
    End If 
    
    Select Case DeBase 
        Case 2 
            Select Case toBase 
                Case 10 
                    Convertir = BinToDec(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
                Case 16 
                    Convertir = BinToHex(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
            End Select 
        Case 10 
            Select Case tobase 
                Case 2 
                    Convertir = DecToBin(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
                Case 16 
                    Convertir = DecToHex(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
            End Select 
        Case 16 
            Select Case tobase 
                Case 2 
                    Convertir = HexToBin(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
                Case 10 
                    Convertir = HexToDec(numToConvert) 
                    Exit Function 
            End Select 
    End Select 
End Function 


Private Function Verificar(valor As String, _ 
                  bag As String) As Boolean 
    
    Dim i As Integer 
    Verificar = True 
    For i = 1 To Len(valor) 
        If InStr(1, bag, Mid(valor, i, 1)) = 0 Then 
            Verificar = False 
            Exit Function 
        End If 
    Next i 
    
End Function
```

Cuando le doy ejecutar pregunta el número a convertir, la base del número ingresado, el número de la base a convertir sin problema pero cuando llego a este punto el programa tira el error del titulo y no se como corregirlo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126712/discussion-on-question-by-alejandro-caro-error-en-tiempo-de-ejecucion-variable).

Comment: Entonces onces necesito o ver la clase completa y que hacen las funciones de conversión. Antes de eso. En la función .Convertir , antes del Select ponle un MsgBox "select",vbinfo...,  Al final del select le pones otro y cada case ponle un MsgBox. Me dices cuales salen.

Comment: la clase es la que está arriba. Es todo el código que puse

Comment: En el chat te he puesto unas consulta entra la chat has lo que digo a n el comentario de arriba. Pon los MsgBox dónde te digo. Tienes otras funcion nes Verificar, HexTo ñDec DecTo. Acabo de ver qué tienes una variable `public Convertir as Object`. Creo que ese es tu problema que significa. Bórrala o cámbiale el nombre solo a la variable.

Comment: Puse lo que me dijiste pero sigue tirando el mismo error igual

Comment: Puedo postear el programa completo

Comment: Es tu variable Convertir de arriba bórrala o cámbiale de nombre. Está haciendo referencia a esa variable que estabnula. No me percate de eso. Borra public Convertir as Object que tienes arriba en la clase.

Comment: No, si hago es me dice No se encontró el método o miembro de datos

Comment: No, hay algo que no se está mostrando pon la clase completa y el formulario completo. No puedes tener la función y la variable

Comment: La única forma que puedas tener la propidas Convertir como una función sonnennlos GET y SET. Es Visual Basic 6 . Cierto?

Comment: Si, es Visual Basic 6.0. Está en la etiqueta de la pregunta

Comment: Postié el programa completo

Comment: Lo que te digo esbque la clase no puede tener una propiedad pública `Convertir` y a su vez una función `Convertir`. Para mí que la función Convertir la tienes fuera de la clase, es decir en otro módulo.

Comment: Te mostré el programa completo, es la única clase que hay

Comment: Si quítale el `.` para quede el `MsgBox Convertir(...)`. Tu problema es el `.`. Me avisas para poner la respuesta la explicacion

Comment: Me dice no coinciden los tipos

Comment: A ver. El punto indica clsConvert.Convert

Comment: Ponle a Convertir que devuelva a n String. Ahora ya no es el mismo mensaje. Ahora es porque devuelves un Object. Asegúrate de devolver un String.

Comment: Tira error igual

Comment: O puedes hacer esto: `MsgBox Str(Convertir(...)),..` y no cambies nada (el `.` si lo quitas.

Comment: Sigue tirando error. Igual deja, que me lo corrija otra persona. Igual gracias por preocuparte

Comment: Otra persona te va a decir lo mismo. Bueno aquí quedamos.

Comment: Dale, así quedamos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes dos problemas:

1. Estás invocando a la función Convertir como si fuera un objeto Convertir de tu clase
2. Está usando MsgBox para mostrar el resultado de la funcion n Convertir que devuelve un  Objeto.

La solución:

1. Cambiamos en el formulario l llamado a la funcion en lugar que a la propiedad

Cambiamos

```
   MsgBox .Convertir (...)
```

Por

```
  MsgBox Convertir(...)
```

2. Aseguramos que la funcion devuelva un string:

```
Option Explicit

' función que convierte de número Hexadecimal a Decimal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function HexToDec(ByVal HexStr As String) As Double
    Dim mult As Double
    Dim DecNum As Double
    Dim ch As String
    mult = 1
    DecNum = 0
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(HexStr) To 1 Step -1 'Len es longitud de la Cadena
        ch = Mid(HexStr, i, 1) 'Mid es la subcadena i es la posición final y el 1 es la cantidad de caracteres que se pretende extraer
        If (ch >= "0") And (ch <= "9") Then
            DecNum = DecNum + (Val(ch) * mult) 'Val convierte a número la Cadena o el carácter
        Else
            If (ch >= "A") And (ch <= "F") Then
                DecNum = DecNum + ((Asc(ch) - Asc("A") + 10) * mult)
            Else
                If (ch >= "a") And (ch <= "f") Then
                    DecNum = DecNum + ((Asc(ch) - Asc("a") + 10) * mult) ' La función Asc _ nos permite obtener el código ASCII de un de terminado carácter.
                Else
                    HexToDec = 0
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
        End If
        mult = mult * 16
    Next i
    HexToDec = DecNum
End Function


' función que convierte de número Decimal a Hexadecimal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function DecToHex(ByVal DecNum As Double) As String
    Dim remainder As Integer
    Dim HexStr As String
    HexStr = ""
    Do While DecNum <> 0
        remainder = DecNum Mod 16
        If remainder <= 9 Then
            HexStr = Chr(Asc(remainder)) & HexStr 'La Función Chr actúa a la _ inversa de la función Asc, esto quiere decir, que a partir de un determinado número nos devolverá el caracter ASCII.
        Else
            HexStr = Chr(Asc("A") + remainder - 10) & HexStr
        End If
        DecNum = DecNum \ 16
    Loop
    If HexStr = "" Then HexStr = "0"
    DecToHex = HexStr
End Function


' función que convierte de número Decimal a Binario
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function DecToBin(ByVal DecNum As Double) As String
    Dim BinStr As String
    BinStr = ""
    Do While DecNum <> 0
        If (DecNum Mod 2) = 1 Then
            BinStr = "1" & BinStr
        Else
            BinStr = "0" & BinStr
        End If
        DecNum = DecNum \ 2
    Loop
    If BinStr = "" Then BinStr = "0000"
    DecToBin = BinStr
End Function


' función que convierte de número Binario a número Decimal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function BinToDec(ByVal BinStr As String) As Double
    Dim mult As Double
    Dim DecNum As Double
    mult = 1
    DecNum = 0
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Len(BinStr) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(BinStr, i, 1) = "1" Then
            DecNum = DecNum + mult
        End If
        mult = mult * 2
    Next i
    BinToDec = DecNum
End Function


' función que convierte de número Hexadecimal a número Bbinario
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Public Function HexToBin(ByVal HexStr As String) As String
    Dim BinStr As String
    BinStr = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(HexStr)
        BinStr = BinStr & DecToBin(HexToDec(Mid(HexStr, i, 1)))
    Next i
    HexToBin = BinStr
End Function


' función que convierte de número Binario a Hexadecimal
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function BinToHex(ByVal BinStr As String) As String
    Dim HexStr As String
    HexStr = ""
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To Len(BinStr) Mod 4 Step 4
        HexStr = HexStr & DecToHex(BinToDec(Mid(BinStr, i + 1, Len(BinStr))))
    Next i
    BinToHex = HexStr
End Function

'función que retorna el valor
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Public Function Convertir(ByVal numToConvert As String, _
                 ByVal DeBase As Integer, _
                 ByVal tobase As Integer) As String
                 
    
    
        Select Case DeBase
            
        Case 2
            If Not Verificar(CStr(numToConvert), "01") Then
                Convertir = "Base 2 sólo puede contener 0 y 1"
                Exit Function
            End If
        Case 10
            If Not Verificar(CStr(numToConvert), "0123456789") Then
                Convertir = "Base 10 sólo puede contener de '0' a '9'."
                Exit Function
            End If
        Case 16
            If Not Verificar(CStr(numToConvert), "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef") Then
                Convertir = "La Base 16 sólo puede contener " & _
                    " de '0' a '9' y de 'A' a 'F' o de 'a' a 'f'."
                Exit Function
            End If
        End Select
    
    If DeBase = tobase Then
        Convertir = numToConvert
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Select Case DeBase
        Case 2
            Select Case tobase
                Case 10
                    Convertir = BinToDec(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
                Case 16
                    Convertir = BinToHex(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
            End Select
        Case 10
            Select Case tobase
                Case 2
                    Convertir = DecToBin(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
                Case 16
                    Convertir = DecToHex(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
            End Select
        Case 16
            Select Case tobase
                Case 2
                    Convertir = HexToBin(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
                Case 10
                    Convertir = HexToDec(numToConvert)
                    Exit Function
            End Select
    End Select
End Function


Private Function Verificar(valor As String, _
                  bag As String) As Boolean

    
    Dim i As Integer

    Verificar = True
    For i = 1 To Len(valor)
        If InStr(1, bag, Mid(valor, i, 1)) = 0 Then
            Verificar = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    
End Function
```

El código lo probe de la siguiente con:

```
  MsgBox Convertir("10", 2, 10), vbInformation

  MsgBox Convertir("10", 2, 16), vbInformation

  MsgBox Convertir("10", 16, 10), vbInformation
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127427/discussion-on-answer-by-juan-carlos-guibovich-error-en-tiempo-de-ejecucion-vari).