# Sentencia equivalente al With de Visual Basic con carteles incluidos y llamada a módulo

Tags: c#

Tengo esté módulo de C# con estas variables definidas de la siguiente forma:

```
using System;

namespace Conversor_de_bases_desde_Inputbox_en_C_sharp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of Class1.
    /// </summary>
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            string numero;
            string DeBase;
            int toBase;
            object Convertir;
        }
    }
}
```

Y este código en el botón principal

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            clsConvert withBlock = new Class1()
            {

                //Inputobx para el número a convertir
                numero = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox(" Ingrese el número a convertir ","Ingreso","Ingrese aquí el número");
                if (numero == ""){
                    return;
                }
                //base del número (Decimal - binario o hexadecimal )

                DeBase = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese la base del número que ingresó :" + " Binario = 2, Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16");
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(!(withBlock.DeBase.Length)) & !Information.IsNumeric(withBlock.DeBase)){
                    return; 
                }
                // Si el usuario pulsa Cancelar el
                // InputBox se cierra sin tirar error de no coincidencia de tipos

                if (DeBase == "0"){
                    return;
                }
                // diálogo para especificar la base de la conversión
                // (binario - decimal o hexadecimal -)

                toBase = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese el número de la " + "base a convertir : Binario = 2, " + "Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16");

                if (toBase == 0){
                    return;
                }
                
                // este método Convierte el número y muestra el resultado
                MessageBox.Show(Convertir(numero, DeBase, toBase),"",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
```

Lo que se pretende hacer es asignar los valores a la variables que están el el módulo

Pero funciona mal y quisiera corregirlo.

Comment: que error te da? porque lo que primero veo es mal declarada tu clase class1

Comment: Dice Error de sintaxis, se esperaba ',' (CS1003)  despuésdel inputbox y otros errores más.

Comment: porque estas mezclando c# con visual basic?

Comment: Porque C# no tiene el método inputbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El primer error que veo, es que estas creando las propiedades dentro del constructor, luego si no les accesibilidad con la palabra clave necesaria, por defecto toma el `private`, entonces tu variables estaban creadas en el constructor lo cual ese seria su ámbito y luego solo seria privadas, lo cual no podrías acceder de ninguna forma desde afuera de su clase, En mi ejemplo te las dejo privadas y solo podrás tener darle el valor necesario desde el constructor cuando instancias el objeto.
El método, lo declaras con el tipo que quieras devolver y retornas el resultado sobre ese tipo en la firma del Método.

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1(string from, int to)
    {
        DeBase = from;
        toBase = to;
    }
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    private string DeBase { get; set; }
    private int toBase { get; set; }
    
    public int Convertir ()
    {
        //ejemplo para retornar algo, no recuerdo como convertir ni viene al caso el ejemplo.
        return DeBase / toBase;
    }
}

public class ClaseEjemplo
{
  Class1 clase1 = new Class1("2",1);
  
  private void ConvertirResultado()
  {
    int resultado = clase1.Convertir();
    MessageBox.Show(resultado);
  }
}
```

Comment: Dale, lo pruebo.

Comment: Lo que quiero conservar es la implementación de la sentencia With de Basic. Si entiendes Basic acá está el original en vb 6.0 https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/463492/error-en-tiempo-de-ejecuci%c3%b3n-variable-de-tipo-object-o-la-variable-de-bloque-wi/463501#463501

Comment: lo probé pero tira error en Class1 clase1 = new Class1(2,1xc);

Comment: el mio era un ejemplo,claro que te daria error porque solo te acepta numero, no hexadecimal o cadena de texto. Tenes que cambiar la firma del metodo y parametros segun lo que necesites

Comment: ¿y cómo sería corregido atendiendo al código de la pregunta?

Comment: te cambie el ejemplo, fijate que recibe solo enteros.

Comment: Sí, pero el  MessageBox.Show y resto del código. ¿Dónde va?

Comment: Donde vos lo quieras crear y donde vos lo quieras llamar, la clase ejemplo podria ser tu boton que llama a la clase class1.

Comment: Viste que dice void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
} ahí estaría la llamada a las funciones

Comment: Otra cosa, me gustaría que no solo recibiera enteros, sino cadena de texto, decimales o hexadecimales.

Comment: Podes sobre Cargar el metodo como vos quieras, tu duda ya esta fuera de la pregunta, Lee como se sobrecarga un metodo. Porque se esta ensuciando la respuesta y pregunta por la variedad de consultas que tenes sobre la misma. Y donde no colocaste en exactitud el error que tenias sino que tenemos que decirte cual es el error que se ve de antemano. No intento ser desagradable.

Comment: Publica de forma concisa las preguntas que tengas en otras preguntas aparte y con gusto voy respondiendo o la persona que lo mire antes que yo.

Comment: Dale, igual ya esta parte la tengo resuelta.

Comment: Ya la postié. Si puedes responderla te agradecería mucho

Comment: @AlejandroCaro no veo ninguna pregunta nueva tuya.

Comment: Está acá https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/469479/detectar-si-se-aprieta-cancelar-en-un-inputbox-para-ingresar-un-integer-en-c

Comment: @AlejandroCaro recuerda aceptar todas las respuestas que solucionaron el problema!