# Detectar si se aprieta cancelar en un InputBox para ingresar un Integer en C#

Tags: c#, input

Estoy implementando un programa de Visual Basic.Net a C#

El programa original usa un inputbox, por lo tuve que hacer una referencia a Visual Basic para importar el método inputbox

```
withBlock.DeBase = Convert.ToInt32(Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese la base del número que ingresó :" + " Binario = 2, Octal = 8, Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16"));
```

A diferencia de Visual Basic.Net, C# pedía que lo convirtiera a entero para guardarlo en la variable, ya  que está definida como `int`

```
int DeBase;
```

Tengo esta línea en Visual Basic.Net

```
    If Not (CBool(Len(.DeBase))) And Not (IsNumeric(.DeBase)) Then Exit Sub ' Si el usuario pulsa Cancelar el
    ' InputBox se cierra sin tirar error de no coincidencia de tipos
```

Esto lo que hace es detectar si el usuario pulsa cancelar, pero la implementación en C# no anda bien. ¿Cómo sería implementado correctamente en C#?

Comment: y que Error te da? siempre es mejor decir que error y en que linea para no tener que interpretar todo el codigo.

Comment: Como verás, esto está en Visual Basic.Net Cuando lo implemento marca error, edito la pregunta y posteo el intento de implementarlo en C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El codigo tiene error, si cancelas la respuesta es un `string` entonces queres convertir una cadena en numero, y luego te faltaria unas validaciones. En primer lugar si vos apretas cancelar te devuelve una cadena vacia el input. Entonces en primera instancia deberias guardar el valor en un `string`, segundo si el valor es hexadecimal tambien seria un `string`.
Entonces una vez con el resultado, si es vacio, frenas el codigo, si lo puede convertir, significa que son numeros lo que ingresaron y ahi lo mandas a tu logica correspondiente, y si no lo puede convertir y no es vacio es porque es un `hexadecimal`.

Con el metodo `int.TryParse` si lo puede convertir de devuelve un boleando y envia el resultado a la variable NumeroEntero.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string numero = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Ingrese la base del número que ingresó :" + " Binario = 2, Octal = 8, Decimal = 10, o Hexadecimal = 16");

        int NumeroEntero = 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numero))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!int.TryParse(numero, out NumeroEntero))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ConvertirHexadecimalADecimal(numero));
            return;
        }
        var resultado =  ConvertirADecimal(numero); 

        MessageBox.Show(resultado); 
    }

    private string ConvertirADecimal(string numero)
    {
        //Logica para convertir
        return $"Convertir a Decimal: El numero ingresado es: {numero}";
    }

    private string ConvertirHexadecimalADecimal(string numero)
    {
        //Logica para convertir
        return $"El numero ingresado es: {numero}";
    }
```

Comment: Estaba mal yo deBase tendría que haberla definido como string en lugar de int. Lo pruebo.

Comment: Redefino la variable numero como string pero al hacerlo hay que cambiar la firma del método. ¿Cual es el código para cambiar esta firma? Si hago esto tira error Class1 clsConvert = new Class1(1xc,2);

Comment: Te recomiendo aprender lo basico de c#, por dos cosas, porque veo tienes problemas basicos y dudas aun mas basicas, sobre todo esta duda que me pleanteas es de la pregunta anterior, en tu metodo recibe dos parametros int, bueno el que quieras y desees cambialo por string.

Comment: Nunca vi C# lo que pasa. ¿Cuál página me recomiendas para estudiar lo de las firmas del método? Por favor, quiero que me funcione el programa.

Comment: O algun curso por internet youtube, o alguno pago, o te vas a microsoft y ahi tienes toneladas de informacion.

Comment: Por favor. Tengo de la variabe de deBase como from y la segunda clase definida así public Class1(string from, int to) y le cambié abajo public string numero { get; set; } el error quizá está en la clase

Comment: Coloca tu pregunta en otra pregunta porque no termino de adivinar el error. Pero creo que deberias ver con calma el error y resolverlo, porque si conoces sobre lenguajes fuertemente tipados, te daras cuenta del error.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné. Lo postié en inglés. Lo que no sabía era que en las firmas del método los parámetros van entre comillas o Convert.ToString si reciben o retornan parámetros tipo string.

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta relacionada con Substring. Si me ayudaras estaría tremendamente agradecido ya que es lo último que me falta para completar la implementación

Comment: @AlejandroCaro publica otra pregunta.

Comment: Si, ya la había publicado. Es esta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470700/problema-con-la-funci%c3%b3n-substring-en-c?noredirect=1#comment838503_470700