# Problema con la función Substring en C#

Tags: c#

Estoy implementando un programa de conversión de números de Visual Basic.Net a C#. Este es el código original que convierte un número de binario a hexadecimal.

En el lenguaje original no marca error de ningún tipo, pero hace uso de la función mid, que es propia de Basic.

```
Public Function BinToHex(ByVal BinStr As String) As String 
   Dim HexStr As String 
   HexStr = "" 
   Dim i As Integer 
   For i = 1 To Len(BinStr) Step 4 
       HexStr = HexStr & DecToHex(BinToDec(Mid(BinStr, i, Len(BinStr)))) 
   Next i 
   Return HexStr 
End Function
```

En C# tengo el siguiente código:

```
public string BinToHex(string BinStr) {
    string HexStr;
    HexStr = "";
    int i;
    var loopTo = BinStr.Length;
    for (i = 1; i <= loopTo; i +=4){
        HexStr = HexStr + DecToHex(BinToDec(BinStr.Substring((i - 1), BinStr.Length)));
    }
    return HexStr;
}
```

Este código hace uso de la función Substring de C# que, conociendo que se maneja diferente a la función mid de Basic, hay que restarle 1 a la variable que se usa como argumento de la función. Pero al ejecutar la función, para valores mayores a 10000(2), tira el siguiente error. El cartel de error es este:
[image: Cartel de error por función Substring con parámetros inválidos]

Comment: Es mas un problema del tamaño del string puede que tenga menos caracteres de los que tratas de sustraer, ahora bien me gustaría saber que es lo que quieres lograr hacer con ese substring ?

Comment: Ese SubString lo que hac es extraer caracteres de la función a la que llama.

Comment: Si lo se, me refiero con que propósito estas substrayendo los primero 4 caracteres de tu string ?

Comment: Para que haga la cuenta

Comment: Considera usar `Convert.ToInt32()` y `ToString()`, así: `Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32("11001", 2), 16)`

Comment: Si, sería una forma más abreviada, pero quiero seguir la idea de Basic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función quedaría así:
No solo está corregido el programa sino también el error que se arrastraba desde el original.

```
public string BinToHex(string BinStr)
{
    string HexStr = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i <= BinStr.Length % 4; i += 4)
    {
        HexStr = HexStr + DecToHex(BinToDec(BinStr.Substring((i), BinStr.Length)));
    }
    return HexStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que no sabes si cada vez que incrementes 4, tu array de caracteres tiene esa cantidad. Entonces ahora voy a la explicacion:

Cuando vos usas el `.Length`, te da la cantidad de caracteres de tu `string` y pueden ser por ejemplo 17, pero cuando vos recorres ese string para obtener caracteres lo recorres igual que un arreglo, desde la posicion 0, entonces vas desde 0 a 16 y ahi esta tu primer error o enredo donde lo inicias en 1, despues le restas 1 en el metodo substring. Pero tu excepcion es porque sumas de a 4 y el array sigue recorriendo en la posicion 14, le suma 4 y luego quiere extrar del 14 al 17 lo cual te excediste del tamaño del arreglo. entonces con un `if` preguntas si la posicion es menor o igual y solucionas el problema.

```
public string BinToHex(string BinStr)
{
  string HexStr = string.Empty;

  for (int i = 0; i <= BinStr.Length; i += 4)
  {
     if (i + 4 <= BinStr.Length)
     {
       HexStr = HexStr + DecToHex(BinToDec(BinStr.Substring((i), 4)));
     }
  }
  return HexStr;
}
```

Comment: Dale, lo pruebo.

Comment: No funciona bien. Si yo intento convertir 11010(2) a hexadecimal da D cuando lo correcto es que devuelva 1A y si ingreso 101(2) da cartel vacío cunado debería dar 5

Comment: son cosas diferentes, tu problema es System.ArgumentOutRangeExpcetion y eso resuelve mi respuesta. Si tu método no convierte bien no esta en esta pregunta.

Comment: Si, da mal también, pero las salidas deberían dar el mismo resultado erróneo en los dos lenguajes.

Comment: No te entendi, pero siempre amplias las preguntes sobre dudas que no estan escritas. Un lineamiento de stackoverflow es que la pregunta sea una, y no muchas dentro de una pregunta. Si corrijio tu problema marcala como tal y si tenes otra pregunta publicala. despues no hago visual basic y tampoco esta el trabajo de tu metodo explicado aca como para que yo sepa si da bien o mal.

Comment: Si en Basic la función para 11010(2) da 1A(16), que está mal pero es un problema de semántica no de sintaxis y para 101(2) da 5(16) (resultado correcto), en su implementación a C# la función debería dar los mismos resultados aunque uno de ellos sea erróneo (11010(2) dar 1A(16), y 101(2) dar 5(16))

Comment: @AlejandroCaro, te fuiste de tema de nuevo, recuerda marca como correcta la respuesta si te sirvio y resolvio el problema planteado en la pregunta. saludos

Comment: No me fui de tema y tampoco la voy a marcar como correcta porque no me sirvió. De todos modos gracias por la paciencia y dedicación a la hora de responder.

Comment: @AlejandroCaro no te entiendo,  si te fuiste de tema,porque vos me comentas que tu metodo el cual no esta en la pregunta da un resultado incorrecto, y tu pregunta y problema era el ArgumentOutRangeExpcetion. lo cual resuelve mi pregunta.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127932/discussion-between-alejandro-caro-and-ramiro-barone).